# How to customize size of the modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-modal

[image]I want to have a curvy modal like this not at the top but half of the screen and curvy with text at the center, for this I want to customize its size.

How can I do it with bootstrap or angular2 modal? Or any idea with less or angular 2 animation? So far I implemented this:

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content pageColor">
```

and pageColor CSS:

```
.pageColor{
 background-color: rgba(127, 205, 190,0.85);
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
```

with this style it's appearing half of the screen not curvy.

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: it's related with bootstrap remove the angular2 tag

Comment: see the updated question

Comment: Its like change the background shape of modal view like circle or square or curve

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you need, but I think that I had already do that, simply overriding the bootstrap css attribut on the modal element.

So just, in your custom css :

```
// or the classes path or whatever to reach the element
.modal {
  width: 75%; // or whatever you want
}
```

Be care of the @media queries that can re-overide your changes.

Comment: Its like change the background shape of modal view like circle or square or curve

Answer (score 0):

use `-webkit-border-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 10px;` for the wrapper. run the code. I guess the pink box is what you need your modal to look like.

```css
.modal-box{ height:250px; width:250px; background:#ccc; float:left; margin-right:10px;}

.modal-curved{height:250px; width:250px; background:pink;-webkit-border-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 10px; float:left;}
```

```html
<div class="modal-box">
</div>

<div class="modal-curved">
</div>
```